# how to change an item index in listview?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a listView and two buttons (UP , DOWN) and i want to move the selected item up or down.

I've thought about swapping between the selected item and the upper one.. but the code i tried .. doesn't make sense because index is readonly.
also mines or sum doesn't owrk .. i can't mess with index at all.

```
private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index--; // It's ReadOnly.
    }
```

So .. how do i let the user the ability to change a ListViewItem index like how VB let us to change these item index [like in the pic]

[image]

thanks in advance ...

Comment: you should change the order in the source for the list

Comment: @CarstenKönig Can you please explain more .. what order in what source .. i mean a little code might help.

Comment: lol- code? how should I produce code without seeing anything usefull from your code first? - You populate the list's source with date - I don't see how, but you *have* to - and this data is where you should change the order of the items you want *switched*

Comment: @CarstenKönig like M4N just did.

Comment: well but what do you get from this? Sure the user will see the changed ordering but will this data get persistet? I mean there is a reason your user might want to change the order right? What M4N gave is a hack in the UI - AKA sphagetti-code - not a good pattern but go on...

Comment: @CarstenKönig Its a transfer file application .. all i wanted to do is to let user to sort the items he adds (from another listview) .. because the order is important for transferring files .. the send method depends on that index.

Comment: so you take the users data from the form-controls? ... Well hope this is a small application - but you got your answer an this is all that matters here - for a discussion on why this might be not such a great idea in a real/middle-to-big project go ask in "Programmers"

Comment: @CarstenKönig take a look this's my application.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663528/how-to-check-if-the-item-name-subitems-text-is-already-exists-in-another-li

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to [remove the selected item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.removeat.aspx) first, then re-add it at the new position.

E.g to move the item up one position:

```
var currentIndex = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index;
var item = listView1.Items[index];
if (currentIndex > 0)
{
    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(currentIndex);
    listView1.Items.Insert(currentIndex-1, item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is an improvement to M4N answer to handle the re order of an item in the top of the list and make it in the bottom of the list

```
int currentIndex = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index;
ListViewItem item = listView1.Items[currentIndex];
if (currentIndex > 0)
{
    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(currentIndex);
    listView1.Items.Insert(currentIndex - 1, item);
}
else
{
    /*If the item is the top item make it the last*/
    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(currentIndex);
    listView1.Items.Insert(listView1.Items.Count, item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of observable collections you are also able to call: .Move(currentindex, newindex);

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654933(v=vs.110).aspx)